# AngularFire2 Query

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2

[For the image click here: JSON Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bPYR.png)
I got a JSON like this and I'm trying to only get results that have a 'naamKort' equal to 'NEC'.

I currently got this:

```
getData(onUpdate) {
        this.db.list('/sndata/wedstrijden', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'teamThuis'.'naamKort',
                equalTo: 'NEC',
            }
        }).subscribe((data) => {
            onUpdate(data);
            this.gamesObservable.emit(data);
        });
    }
```

But the `orderByChild: 'teamThuis'.'naamKort',` doesn't work. So i'm unsure on how to exactly use equal to when the value is inside a different value. If I do a query for let's say 'tijd' equalTo '20:30' it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Apparently I needed to use:

```
 orderByChild: 'teamThuis/naamKort',
```